# CSS specificity beat inline with !important

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-specificity

Here is my site: http://stage.samkeddy.com/

It's responsive using a couple media queries and a mobile menu button powered by javascript.

Here is the javascript for the menu button:

```
function toggleMenu () {
    if (menuIsVisible == false) {
        collapsibleMenu.style.height = 'auto';
        content.style.paddingTop = '290px';
        menuIsVisible = true;
    }
    else {
        collapsibleMenu.style.height = '0';
        content.style.paddingTop = '80px';
        menuIsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

so you can see that I need to adjust the padding at the top of the content div, in order to offset the menu

But if resize to the mobile size, open the menu, and then resize back to the desktop size, the padding isn't fixed by the media query, because there's still an inline style from the javascript. I tried making the padding on the desktop version !important, but it the padding still doesn't change when resized, even though according to [this](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) !important beats inline.

You can test for yourself by opening the size (how it should look), resizing to a mobile width(the nav will disappear, and you will see the menu button), clicking the menu button (leave the menu open), then resize the site back to a desktop width. You will see the padding is still there. If you inspect it, you can see the original padding is crossed out in favor of the inline style.

I know this would be possible by monitoring the width with javascript and setting the padding then, but I really don't want to do that, and don't think I should have to.

EDIT: solved

First, I should have been adding classes, rather than adding CSS with my javascript.

Then I assumed that putting !important outside of a media query would make it only show up on desktop, but it took over all media queries. So placing just this in a query made it work. Note that if I was using 2 separate menus (mobile/desktop), I wouldn't need this, but since it was fixed and the #content needed padding, it had to be done. But using this technique you can also use only a single menu, but doing the height for the menu this way. I've demonstrated the technique in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JFvay

Comment: why are you not using @media queries to determine the size of your menu... using javascript/jQuery usage for these styles only uncovers the man hole you're about to fall into.

Comment: Also you can just stop using those inline styles. Create a couple of classes and give the elements one or the other classes. (But yes of course use media queries when possible.)

Comment: So your !important style shows up in your dev tools? If not, maybe you have a syntax error somewhere before that style.

Comment: Media queries do change the size the of the menu, the javascript just hides / unhides it. I will try using classes and then update.

Comment: It is possible to have two different menues without duplicating the htm. Use the media queries to format the page differently. You may have to use different display properties like fixed, mixed with margins - but it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this code to your stylesheet should solve the problem, I just tried this on your website using the Developer Tools and it's working:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 643.2px) {
    #content {
        padding-top: 80px !important;
    }
}
```

Although I'd strongly recommend you to create a separate navigation menu for mobile devices and resort to using @media-queries to display it.

Comment: I'm going to try doing 2 navigations. I can see how that can be easier to code for, though it's a shame having two identical sets of html for it.

Comment: not sure if you can use php or not, but maybe you can write your own function if you are using php to do the menu for you. That way you are not making 2 separate sets. Or depending on your menu you can set it up to break down fairly easily.

Comment: This was the key to my success. I assumed that putting !important outside of a media query would make it only show up on desktop, but it took over all media queries. So placing just this in a query made it work. Note that if I was using 2 separate menus (mobile/desktop), I wouldn't need this, but since it was fixed and the #content needed padding, it had to be done. But using this technique you can also use only a single menu, but doing the height for the menu this way. I've demonstrated the technique in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JFvay

Answer (score 2):

Your problem at heart is that you're mixing CSS and in-line styles. As a general rule, avoid placing specific CSS properties directly on elements, whether in HTML, by using `element.style.<property> =`, or via jQuery's `.css()` feature. Instead, you should define the properties you want as CSS rules, using classes:

```css
#collapsible-menu                       { height: auto;  }
#content                                { padding-top: 290px; }
#someelt.menu-visible #collapsible-menu { height: 0; }
#someelt.menu-visible #content          { padding-top: 80px; }
```

where `someelt` is some higher-level ancestor element. Then, your JS becomes simply

```javascript
function toggleMenu() {
    document.getElementById('someelt').classList.toggle('menu-visible');
}
```

If you are targeting browsers which do not support `classList` (see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist)), jQuery provides its own version of class toggling.

CSS is not an imperative language, but if you want, you can think of the `#someelt.menu-visible` part of the last two rules above as a kind of `if` statement: "*If* menus are visible, *then* shrink `collapsible-menu` to zero height", etc. In this metaphor of CSS as a kind of programming language (which it is), the presence of the `menu-visible` class of `#someelt` could be thought of as a kind of boolean "variable", I suppose. Most likely, you will no longer need a corresponding variable in your JS.

Anyway, the advantage of this is that people looking at your code can see *all* your CSS-related logic just by looking at the CSS file, instead of having to look at both CSS and JS, and you can change CSS-related things in just one place.

Comment: That's not an accurate description, particularly if you consider inline style attributes to be outside the realm of CSS. !important affects all style declarations participating in the cascade, *including* style attributes. If an inline style declaration doesn't have !important, then any !important declaration should override it. (And of course, if an inline style declaration does have !important, it'll still win.)

Comment: The description is taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). There is a lot of inaccurate information in that particular article. I see why it says "This article is in need of a technical review." - it does need one, *badly*.

Comment: MDN description now removed.

Comment: Thank you very much, this comment helped me achieve what I was looking for. I defined #content.openMenu and #mobile-nav.openMenu in the css, then just added the class to both elements via javascript. I also had to part of the other answer here, which was to define min-width, and move the padding-top for content there with an important flag, so it would overwrite when it when it was desktop.